.Net export to CSV file using javascript, and replacing character
I'm using .NET 8.0.
I am exporting a grid to CSV file using javascript...
One column of the grid has this value
AAA;BBB;CCC 

When I export to CSV  I need that the cell that contains this value appear one under the other in the same cell ,like this
Column1   Name       Value

1         apple         AAA
                        BBB
                        CCC
2         orange        DDD  

I have this function in JS
function GenerateCSV(table_id, name) {
    // Select rows from table_id
    var rows = document.querySelectorAll('table#' + table_id + ' tr');
    // Construct csv
    var csv = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll('td, th');
        for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
            // Clean innertext to remove multiple spaces and jumpline (break csv)
            var data = cols[j].innerText.replace(/(\s\s)/gm, ' ').replace(";", "\r\n")
              row.push('"' + data + '"');
         }
        csv.push(row.join(','));
    }
    var csv_string = csv.join('\n');

    var filename = name + '.csv';
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.style.display = 'none';
    link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    link.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv_string));
    link.setAttribute('download', filename);
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}

In this line
var data = cols[j].innerText.replace(/(\s\s)/gm, ' ').replace(";", "\r\n")

I am replacing ";" for "\r\n"
it half works.. It just replace the first character ";" instead of replacing all ";"
It shows
 Column1   Name       Value
    
    1      apple         AAA
                         BBB;CCC

How can make the replacement on the entire line?
Thanks

Just need to replace it with a global regex search:
var data = cols[j].innerText.replace(/(\s\s)/gm, ' ').replace(/;/g, "\r\n")

Note sure what the \s\s is about tho but keeping it in there just in case (idk the format of your data)
